# Problems with IDocumentQuery.ExecuteNextAsync()

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have standard lines of code, to fetch data with pagination. It used to work until a month ago, and then stopped. On running ExecuteNextAsync() it stops execution, and displays this following information in Output window:

DocDBTrace Information: 0 : DocumentClient with id 2 disposed.

DocDBTrace Information: 0 : DocumentClient with id 1 disposed.

Not  Working Code:

```
var query = 
client.CreateDocumentQuery(
                UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, "TestCollection"), "select c.id from TestCollection c",
                new FeedOptions
                {
                    //MaxDegreeOfParallelism=-1,
                    MaxItemCount = maxItemCount,
                    PopulateQueryMetrics=true
                    //RequestContinuation = requestContinuation,
                    //EnableScanInQuery = true,
                    //EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true
                });
                var queryAll = query.AsDocumentQuery();

            var results = new List<TDocument>();
     while (queryAll.HasMoreResults)
            {
                try
                {
                    var result = await queryAll.ExecuteNextAsync();
                    var queryMetrics = result.QueryMetrics;

                    if (result.ResponseContinuation != null) requestContinuation = result.ResponseContinuation;
//Do something here
  }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
```

For the same client object, Create/Update or fetching all items together is working. So JsonSerializer or DocumentClient object cannot be a problem.
Working code:

```
var query2 = client.CreateDocumentQuery(
                UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionName), "select * from TestCollection c",
                new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1 });
                //.Where(l => l.Id == qId);

            var testData2= query2.ToList();
```

This has stopped our services and their development. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `select c.id from TestCollection c` is this correct? I would expect it to be `select c.id from c` as c is already TestCollection due to the collection URI pointing at it

Comment: Yeah just tested with [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut) and it worked without the collection name in the query. Added the answer.

Comment: I realize this doesn't answer your question, but performing a query on a single document's ID is a waste of resources. You should consider using ReadDocumentAsync. In my experience, this call uses 66% fewer RUs and takes less time

Comment: I agree to that. The example was given here just to show that in general query and document client object are working.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong.

`UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, "TestCollection")` will already let the SDK know what to query.

If you simply change

`select c.id from TestCollection c`

to

`select c.id from c`

It will work. Currently it is failing to resolve the c alias because you also have TestCollection there.

The only reason your other queries that use `*` are working is because you aren't using the `c.` there.

Comment: It did not work. I tried UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, "TestCollection"), "select * from c"/"select c.id from c".
And to be honest, I tried all combinations of select *. Did you try with ExecuteNextAsync(). As that's where the program exit with no exception. Just the message in Output window

Comment: It seems to be working for me. Can you do me a favor ans let that exception that you are suppressing be thrown in order to see what might be there?

Comment: Is your collection partitioned btw?

Comment: 1.Collection is not partitioned.
2. it does not reach to the catch block. Code execution exits on ExecuteNextAsync() line itself.

Comment: Ok just to confirm. I tried the exact same piece of code and it works. You are possibly having a partitioned collection and you are not enabling the cross partition query option which in return causes this action to throw an exception which you are suppressing. The only other reason can be the max item count that you are setting which you are not showing. https://i.imgur.com/Eu1dlNP.png

Comment: Just tested with a  non partitioned collection as well and i still got the exact same result. What is the max item count you are setting? Here is a working code piece with a non partitioned collection: https://i.imgur.com/gNrQ9h3.png

Comment: I agree to that, But when the same code snippet wasn't working for a different partitioned one, I created a TestCollection(with one field-id) to test. And this was working fine until March. I recently ran it again. Max item count is 100.

Comment: Very bizarre mate. What's the SDK version you are using?

Comment: Agreed to bizarre and some more. Version is 1.17.0. Next I was thinking to upgrade to 1.19. Since the query execution is same for local emulator and Cosmos DB. Any other suggestions?

Comment: This is not self promo but can you please install [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut) and give that a go? It exposes the DocumentClient so you can just use that to create your query. It might be some version issue. As i can actually get it working with this, it might work giving it a go.

Comment: I can give it a try. I'll get back to you on the results.